Some commands take incredibly long to execute when having an active internet connection
I'm running macOS Sequoia Version 15.1 and currently experience issues running commands in a zsh terminal while connected to the internet.
When running commands like git status, they take incredibly long on the first run. Also, for example, when running git log --online, I can see how the commits pop up line by line, where it takes approximately 500ms to print one line. This only happens on the first run and when connected to the internet. If I turn off wifi, the commands execute immediately, as expected. It doesn't only affect commands like git; things like pnpm info or starting up terminal-based editors also cause the issue.
I've also noted that when running commands, e.g., git rebase -i HEAD~5, those fail with fatal: mmap failed: Operation timed out when I am offline. Is that normal, or could it point to the root cause of this issue?
I've also already tried turning IPv6 on and off. However, there is little difference. I've attached my .zshrc and etc/hosts files, which look acceptable.
.zshrc
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

# pnpm
export PNPM_HOME="/Users/user/Library/pnpm"
case ":$PATH:" in
  *":$PNPM_HOME:"*) ;;
  *) export PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH" ;;
esac
export PATH="$HOME/pdfsizeopt:$PATH"
# pnpm endexport PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/pax/bin:$PATH"
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

/etc/resolv.conf
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
search fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1

scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fritz.box
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  if_index : 11 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : fritz.box
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.178.1
  if_index : 11 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGScg                 en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#11            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178        link#11            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1/32   link#11            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1      44:4e:6d:49:2e:b2  UHLWIir               en0   1160
192.168.178.62     f4:34:f0:5b:ba:97  UHLWIi                en0   1135
192.168.178.126    e6:ea:1c:d5:4c:3   UHLWI                 en0    694
192.168.178.137    70:22:fe:bb:36:90  UHLWIi                en0   1131
192.168.178.162/32 link#11            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.162    da:e1:85:a4:42:98  UHLWI                 lo0
192.168.178.164    66:13:e4:58:a1:68  UHLWIi                en0    906
192.168.178.168    f2:69:fd:94:3:e2   UHLWI                 en0    926
224.0.0/4          link#11            UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#11            UCS                   en0      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                                 Flags               Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                            UGcIg               utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun1                            UGcIg               utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun2                            UGcIg               utun2
default                                 fe80::%utun3                            UGcIg               utun3
default                                 fe80::%utun4                            UGcIg               utun4
default                                 fe80::%utun5                            UGcIg               utun5
::1                                     ::1                                     UHL                   lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                             UcI                   lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                                  UHLI                  lo0
fe80::7013:ffff:fe6c:333d%awdl0         72:13:ff:6c:33:3d                       UHLI                  lo0
fe80::7013:ffff:fe6c:333d%llw0          72:13:ff:6c:33:3d                       UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::ce25:868f:3d4e:8201%utun0         UcI                 utun0
fe80::ce25:868f:3d4e:8201%utun0         link#15                                 UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::d962:30e0:b6bc:1608%utun1         UcI                 utun1
fe80::d962:30e0:b6bc:1608%utun1         link#16                                 UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::cc4e:fad5:6eab:f9ff%utun2         UcI                 utun2
fe80::cc4e:fad5:6eab:f9ff%utun2         link#17                                 UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun3/64                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3           UcI                 utun3
fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3           link#18                                 UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun4/64                         fe80::596:f7e1:8838:b3c2%utun4          UcI                 utun4
fe80::596:f7e1:8838:b3c2%utun4          link#19                                 UHLI                  lo0
fe80::%utun5/64                         fe80::c4b3:a896:ae0b:b161%utun5         UcI                 utun5
fe80::c4b3:a896:ae0b:b161%utun5         link#20                                 UHLI                  lo0
ff00::/8                                ::1                                     UmCI                  lo0
ff00::/8                                link#13                                 UmCI                awdl0
ff00::/8                                link#14                                 UmCI                 llw0
ff00::/8                                fe80::ce25:868f:3d4e:8201%utun0         UmCI                utun0
ff00::/8                                fe80::d962:30e0:b6bc:1608%utun1         UmCI                utun1
ff00::/8                                fe80::cc4e:fad5:6eab:f9ff%utun2         UmCI                utun2
ff00::/8                                fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3           UmCI                utun3
ff00::/8                                fe80::596:f7e1:8838:b3c2%utun4          UmCI                utun4
ff00::/8                                fe80::c4b3:a896:ae0b:b161%utun5         UmCI                utun5
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                                     UmCI                  lo0
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::ce25:868f:3d4e:8201%utun0         UmCI                utun0
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::d962:30e0:b6bc:1608%utun1         UmCI                utun1
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::cc4e:fad5:6eab:f9ff%utun2         UmCI                utun2
ff01::%utun3/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3           UmCI                utun3
ff01::%utun4/32                         fe80::596:f7e1:8838:b3c2%utun4          UmCI                utun4
ff01::%utun5/32                         fe80::c4b3:a896:ae0b:b161%utun5         UmCI                utun5
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                                     UmCI                  lo0
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::ce25:868f:3d4e:8201%utun0         UmCI                utun0
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::d962:30e0:b6bc:1608%utun1         UmCI                utun1
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::cc4e:fad5:6eab:f9ff%utun2         UmCI                utun2
ff02::%utun3/32                         fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3           UmCI                utun3
ff02::%utun4/32                         fe80::596:f7e1:8838:b3c2%utun4          UmCI                utun4
ff02::%utun5/32                         fe80::c4b3:a896:ae0b:b161%utun5         UmCI                utun5


/etc/resolv.conf, the routing table & any firewall instructions are going to be more relevant. Also telling us how it is all connected to the internet will help.

Thank you @BobGoddard, I've added more information. I'm using the default firewall provided by macOS activated in the system settings. The laptop is connected to the internet via 5GHz WiFi.

Could be a slow DNS relay in your Fritzbox. Try changing the DNS your Mac is using to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 instead of that 192.168.178.1 address.

I do not think it is related to my Fritzbox. I've been able to reproduce the issue when connected to my iPhone's hotspot right now.

I just changed my DNS to Cloudflare, but the problem persists.
